# What is pictured in this SHERLOC camera?

Tags: identify-this-object, perseverance

[This picture](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/SIF_0026_0669254226_049EBY_N0030792SRLC07005_0000LUJ) was taken by one of the cameras on the Perseverance rover. What is pictured here ? And what is the purpose of this image?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is a camera calibration target, specifically the Intensity Target Maze.

[image: A picture of the three "outreach" targets]

Purpose:

> The top target row consists of
> five targets used for SHERLOC calibration including
> Raman and fluorescence spectral accuracy, response
> curve, ambient light reflection, spectral mapping, and
> laser parameters.

and

> Three targets additionally serve unique education
> and public outreach purposes. The Mars meteorite, a
> slice of Sayh al Uhaymir 008 (SaU008) collected in
> Oman in 1999, will represent the first piece of Mars to
> be returned to the planet’s surface (Fig. 3a). The intensity target design incorporates an intricate maze (Fig.
> 3b), and the clear polycarbonate space suit visor material is backed by a distinctive Geocaching trackable
> marker (Fig. 3c).

This image shows the location of the targets on the rover.

[image: The target location is shown on the front of the rover]

SCT = **S**HERLOC **C**amera **T**arget

The target in the question is located in position 4.

Reference: [THE CALIBRATION TARGET FOR THE MARS 2020 SHERLOC INSTRUMENT](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2019/pdf/2717.pdf)

Comment: As a Holmes fan, I am pleased to note that there is a picture/icon of Sherlock Holmes on Mars.

Comment: _"The Mars meteorite, a slice of Sayh al Uhaymir 008 (SaU008) collected in Oman in 1999, will represent the first piece of Mars to be returned to the planet’s surface"_ - I'm disappointed we didn't get an Xbox Achievement in real-life for doing that...